# How to see Google cloud functions invocations per day or month?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

In Google cloud metrics, I created a metric to monitor how many times a google cloud function is invoked

cloud functions -> functions -> executions

[image]

But this shows different values than the very small chart in Firebase -> Invocations/hour

[image]

1. What's the issue here?
2. How to change the charts' timezone in GCP to show the time in my timezone? The default timezone for the charts listed on Google cloud is fine, but the Metrics chart timezone is different.

Comment: To see the exact number of invocations for a particular Google Cloud Function, you can use the Cloud Functions Execution Count metric in the Cloud Functions metrics explorer. The discrepancy between the metrics shown in the Cloud Functions dashboard and the Firebase dashboard could be due to different intervals or aggregation methods or different functions being tracked. To change the timezone of the charts in GCP, click on the gear icon in the upper right corner of the chart and select the desired timezone. You may also contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

Comment: @Chanpols Thank you for letting me how to change the timezone. I figured out how to make a chart that matches the Firebase chart and posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by trying multiple charts and seeing how other default charts are done

So we should use functions -> executions

[image]

The aligner and the aggregator should be set to "sum"

[image]

And the chart type is line chart.

As for the timezone, as **Chanpols** indicated in the comment, there's a gear icon on the top right where you can change the timezone.